# How to use DataFrame.rename to rename a dataframe index (not inplace)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm highly confused by the [DataFrame.rename docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename).

They suggest I should be able to rename indexes the same way as columns.
It ain't so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=["A"])
df.index.name = 'i'

print df
print df.rename(columns={"A":"B"})  # Success! A is renamed B
print df.rename(index={"i":"j"})    # No-op
print df.rename({"i":"j"}, axis=0)    # No-op
print df.rename({"i":"j"}, axis=1)    # No-op

print df.rename(index={"i":"j"}, axis=1) #  Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'.
print df.rename(index={"i":"j"}, axis="index")  #  Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'.
print df.rename(index={"i":"j"}, axis="columns") #  Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'.
print df.rename(index={"i":"j"}, axis=0) #  Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'.
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html).

Comment: That method is deprecated

Comment: Hmmm... `df.rename_axis({"i":"j"}, axis=0)` is deprecated. Not the method you suggested.

Comment: Using `df.rename_axis` to rename the axis itself (e.g. `df.rename_axis('j', axis=0)`) is **not deprecated**. Only using `df.rename_axis` to change index *labels* is deprecated (e.g. `df.rename_axis({0: 'foo'}, axis=0)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` + `index` will change the index not the ***index name***

```
df.rename(index={0:'j'})
Out[310]: 
   A
i   
j  1
```

`rename_axis` will change the index name

```
df.rename_axis('j',axis=0)
Out[315]: 
   A
j   
0  1
```

Since `rename_axis` is going to deprecated

```
df.index.rename('j',inplace=True)
df
Out[328]: 
   A
j   
0  1
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest `rename_axis` if it's deprecated - will likely disappear in the future.

Comment: This looks right. I'd misunderstood these docs (would could also be more clear). Thanks.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis yep, I update index.rename :-) , thank you :-)

Comment: It looks like rename_axis only gets a deprecation warning if you provide a map as the parameter. I can't use in-place operations because because they're not appropriate for large projects where the dataframe is shared and assumed to be immutable.

Comment: @user48956 yep. I got u.  What we can do is follow the update scheduled , make sure they are not deprecation :-)